# Probability recursion

Tags: probability

Im trying to find the recursive relation that find the probability that when tossing a coin over and over the pattern tth show for the first time on the nth trial.  I'm really stumped on this, I tried using the law of the total probability on the first outcome(head or tails ) to no avail and defining two events that tth doesn't appear in the first n trials and appears in the nth trial didn't work.  How is this done??

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Are you asking if you want $P(TTH| n tosses)$: the probability of getting TTH given n tosses?

Comment: No I'm trying to find the probability that the pattern tth appears for the first time at the nth toss

Comment: This reminds me of Markov Chains. I'll research for a bit, but you might want to look into "first-hitting times" or "first-passage times" regarding Markov Chains

Comment: Hmm those look too advanced, I tried this now maybe it can be continued,  by the law of total probability p(tth first time at nth toss)= p (first is h )p(tth first time at nth toss given first is h) + p (first is t) p( tth first time at nth tossing given first is t) , the second probability looks like its p (tth first time at n-1th toss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help:  OEIS sequence [A000071](http://oeis.org/A000071) counts "the number of 001-avoiding binary words of length $n-3$."

To expand on this, the probability of getting TTH for the first time on the $n$th toss is clearly ${1\over8}p(n-3)$, where $p(n-3)$ is the probability of avoiding TTH in a string of length $n-3$.  Now a TTH-avoiding string of length $k$ either starts with an H followed by a TTH-avoiding string of length $k-1$, with a TH followed by a TTH-avoiding string of length $k-2$, or consists solely of T's.  Thus

$$p(k)={1\over2}p(k-1)+{1\over4}p(k-2)+{1\over2^k}$$

where $p(0)=p(1)=1$ (from which the recursion gives $p(2)=1$ as well).  If we write $q(k)=2^kp(k)$, the recursion is $q(k)=q(k-1)+q(k-2)+1$, leading to the sequence $1,2,4,7,12,20,33,\ldots$ of OEIS [A000071](http://oeis.org/A000071).  Writing $q(k)=f(k)-1$ gives $f(k)=f(k-1)+f(k-2)$, showing why the Fibonacci numbers play the role they do.

**Added later**:  Just for definiteness, let $P(n)$ denote the probability of getting TTH for the first time on the $n$th toss.  Then the recursion requested by the OP is precisely

$$P(n) = {1\over2}P(n-1)+{1\over4}P(n-2)+{1\over2^n}$$

where $P(1)=P(2)=0$, so that $P(3)={1\over8}$, $P(4)={1\over2}P(3)+{1\over16}={1\over8}$, $P(5)={1\over2}P(4)+{1\over4}P(3)+{1\over32}={1\over8}$, and so forth.  It's easiest to slip appropriate powers of $2$ under the terms of the OEIS sequence:

$${0\over2},{0\over4},{1\over8},{2\over16},{4\over32},{7\over64},{12\over128},{20\over256},{33\over512},{54\over1024},\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ denote the first time when the motive TTH is completed. To compute the distribution of $S$, one considers the Markov chain on the state space $\{0,1,2,3\}$ whose state at time $n$ is the length of the maximal initial subword of TTH which is at the end of the letters produced at time $n$.

For example, if the initial letters are HTHHTTTHT, the first states of the Markov chain are $0010012231$.

Note that $S$ is the first hitting time $\theta$ of state $3$ by this Markov chain hence one can compute $u_i=E_i(s^\theta)$ where the subscript $i$ means that one starts at state $i$. The usual one-step Markov recursion yields
$$
u_0=\tfrac12s(u_0+u_1),\quad u_1=\tfrac12s(u_0+u_2),\quad u_2=\tfrac12s(1+u_2),
$$
hence
$$
u_0=\frac{s^3}{(2-s)(4-2s-s^2)}.
$$
Now, $P[S=n]$ is the coefficient of $s^n$ in the power series $u_0$ hence one decomposes $u_0$ as
$$
u_0=1-\frac{2}{2-s}+\frac1{\sqrt5}\frac{a}{a-s}-\frac1{\sqrt5}\frac{b}{b+s},
$$
with $a=\sqrt5-1$ and $b=\sqrt5+1$. Thus, for every $n\geqslant3$,
$$
P[S=n]=[s^n]u_0=-\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{\sqrt5}\frac1{a^n}-\frac1{\sqrt5}(-1)^n\frac1{b^n}\sim\frac1{\sqrt5}\frac1{a^n}.
$$

Comment: Wow I didn't think it'll be this complicated. I have zero knowledge about markov chains. But I appreciate the effort. There is no other way?

Comment: Probably, but you're asking for the first occurence of the subsequence TTH. So, basically (if i were to decipher the above explanation for you), markov chains describes all the ways of going from one state to another. In this case, state $1$ means you have your first $T$, state $2$ means you have 2 consecutive T's i.e: $TT$, state $3$ means $TTH$ and state $0$ for the rest. Every time you flip a coin you either change states or remain in the same state.

Comment: For example: you flipped twice and got $HT$ which means you got to state $1$. If you flip a $T$, you'll get to state $2$ and if you flip an $H$ you get to state $0$

Comment: And that power series is gotten from the fact that to get to state 3 you have to get there from state 2 which to get there you have to be either in state 2 (flipping yet another T) or having been in state 1, which to get there you were before that in state 0. 

I recommend looking into Markov Chains, they're quite fun. Plus it's super practical as in you get how they can be useful.